# Google app engine per-user billing and quotas

Tags: google-app-engine, billing, quotas

Does GAE provide tools for an application to accumulate per-user network usage, data storage etc, for the purposes of user billing and/or quota enforcement, or must an app estimate these stats independently?

Comment: you mean users of your app?

Comment: Yes, individual users of the app, not developers on GAE. My worry is that unless quotes are enforced, some users will blow the budget.